# Azure DevOps - how to create a 2nd Microsoft-hosted Agent Pool

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am using Azure DevOps.

I have 5 Microsoft-hosted agents. And 10 pipelines.
One pipeline in particular can get a bit grabby, so I want to restrict it to use just 2 agents.

But I want my other 9 pipelines to have access to the 3 remaining agents.

I figure Agent Pools is the right way to solve this. By default, Azure DevOps sets us up with 1 single "Azure Pipelines" pool with our self-hosted agents. I would like to split this into 2 pools.

However, when I go to "create new pool" I only get the option to add "self-hosted" agents.

How do I create a new Agent Pool with some of my existing Microsoft-hosted agents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good question because you would assume you could do what you are after, but as far as I know you can't yet. From the docs on [sharing of parallel jobs across projects in a collection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-jobs?view=azure-devops#sharing-of-parallel-jobs-across-projects-in-a-collection)

> Currently, there isn't a way to partition or dedicate parallel job capacity to a specific project or agent pool.

I considered trying to do buckets via capabilities on a subset of my agents, and then companion demands in the pipelines, but that will not work either because [hosted pipelines don't work with demands](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/demands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

In my case we had some greedy pipelines that fan out into multiple parallel jobs, that we had to update to run sequentially with `dependsOn` for each job. I think if your case is relatively simple you could potentially check the queue length or number of running builds in a first stage but that could get complex and might be tough to scale.

Hopefully this feature gets added soon. I will look to see if I can find one to vote up on the developer community forums. I am also interested in other ideas on how to solve for this issue!

Edit found a feature [vote on it here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/721308/limit-parallel-jobs-for-a-pipelinefolder-of-pipeli.html)

Comment: +1 for the feature voting link!